# Why does the voltage measured across a capacitor increase with time

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields, voltage, capacitance

The voltage measured across a capacitor increases over time as current flows through the circuit because more charge is accumulated. I thought however that since voltage is defined as energy/coulomb, the voltage across a capacitor is independent of the total number of electrons.

Comment: This depends on the circuit you're looking at. I'm guessing you're talking about a circuit with a battery, a resistor and a capacitor in parallel. But without specifying this more clearly, this can't be answered properly.

Comment: I don't see how $V=W/q$ might imply that the voltage should be constant.

Answer (score 4):

> I thought however that since voltage is defined as energy/coulomb, the
> voltage across a capacitor is independent of the total number of
> electrons.

The voltage $V$ across the capacitor of capacitance $C$ is not independent of the amount of charge $Q$ on the capacitor. The relationship between them is

$$Q=CV$$

So for a given capacitance, the greater the charge the greater the voltage.

The potential difference $V$ between two points is defined as the work per unit charge required to move the charge between the points. So the voltage between the plates of a capacitor is the work per unit charge required to move the charge between the two plates.

As more and more charge $Q$ is moved between the plates by the charging source (e.g. battery), the voltage $V$ increases thereby requiring even more work by the charging source to add more charge. When the voltage across the capacitor equal the source voltage, the source is no longer capable of adding more charge, and the current stops.

> But why then do capacitors with different surface areas (storing
> different amounts of electrons) store the same amount of energy if
> applied to the same voltage source. Does it take less work to move
> electrons to a capacitor with a bigger surface area?

Capacitors with different surface areas do not store the same amount of energy for the same voltage source.

The energy stored in a capacitor is

$$E=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$$

The parallel plate capacitance, as a function of surface area, is

$$C=\frac{eA}{d}$$

Where $A$ = capacitor plate area, $e$ = electrical permittivity of the dielectric between the plates and $d$ = distance between the plates.

A parallel capacitor with the same dielectric and plate separation,  but having a larger or smaller plate area, has more or less more capacitance.

So not only does a capacitor with different area have a different amount charge, it also stores a different amount of energy.

> Does it take less work to move electrons to a capacitor with a bigger
> surface area?

Yes. Recalling

$$Q=CV$$

The larger the plate, the larger $C$ and and the less work per unit charge $V$ required to store the same amount of charge.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But why then do capacitors with different surface areas (storing different amounts of electrons)  store the same amount of energy if applied to the same voltage source. Does it take less work to move electrons to a capacitor with a bigger surface area?

Comment: @Aliska In response, see the update to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Aliska I added more to my post to answer the last part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that voltage is energy per charge, but by "charge" it is not that ones  accumulated on the capacitor plates.

It means the work done on a *test* charge placed close to one of the charged plates, and being accelerated by the field to the other side. Of course electrostatic force is bigger for bigger charges, and also the work.

So, to get a measure of energy of the system (in that case a capacitor) independent of the *test* charge, (the definition of voltage), it is necessary to divide energy by this charge.

Answer (score 1):

In simple metaphor, it's just like getting water into a ballon from a faucet. regardless of water pressure of the faucet, the pressure of the rubber shell is zero, However it goes higher as it accumulates.
Just like so, Voltage across the capacitor is zero, without electrons accumulated. electron and electron hole is what creates the voltage between the plates, not the voltage from power source directly. Energy/Coulomb is for stationary state, which is not the case. That's why you should be careful when using formula.